# (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting this error (Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/getBook?id=5e3924ba1e1e8a11e8bc1c7c from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)) when the application is proxying. The application loads well on start up but on refresh it throws the error

```
export function getBookWithReviewer(id){
    const request = axios.get(`/api/getBook?id=${id}`)
    return(dispatch)=>{
    request.then(({data})=> {
        let book = data
        axios.get(`/api/getReviewer?id=${book.ownerId}`).then(({data})=>{
            let response={
                book,
                reviewer: data
            }
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({
                type:'GET_BOOK_W_REVIEWER',
                payload:response
            })
        })
    })

    }
```

Comment: connection refused. does your endpoint resolve ok otherwise i.e. outside the application / in Postman etc? Are you potentially having a CORS issue communicating with your endpoint?

Comment: I don't have a cors issue. The problem comes when i make a second request to the api endpoint, /api/getReviewer?id=${book.ownerId}`

Comment: ok, what does the browser show it is hitting? Network tab in chrome. does it resolve to the correct endpoint / path? Perhaps try the full http location. e.g. http://localhost:3001/api/getBook?id=$ etc

Comment: did you find a solution to this?